# Framework VS CocoaPod Libraries

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, cocoapods

**FIXED** - Fixed it. There is a Parse Pods Library, added framework to Pods file and deleted the Parse Framework from project Directory and now I can use it in both

So I'm having trouble accessing frameworks that aren't listed in Cocoapod's website in an open source project that I'm modifying and I'm installing the open source project itself via Cocoapods so the open source project is listed under the Pods Directory.

I can't import the Parse framework in my open source file without an error but I can import it fine in my project Directory files. From constant tampering I've boiled it to some patterns that I found.

```
1) I can import frameworks in my open source files that are already
included by default in xcode like AVFoundation.framework,
Accounts.framework, or Security.framework

2) I can import third party frameworks in my open source file like
Bolts only when they're listed in Cocoapods

3) I can't access the Parse framework in my open source file even if
it's linked/listed under "Build Phases" ==> "Link Binary With
Libraries" (Relative to Group is checked) Again, I can access the
framework in my own project directory but not in my open source
files listed under the Pods Directory. I can't find the Parse
framework in Cocoapods

4) I have found the ParseUI framework in Cocoapods so I've included
that in my Podfile but since ParseUI is listed in Cocoapods but not
the Parse framework itself I'm guessing when I import ParseUI to my
file, it's dynamically linking to the Parse framework but dynamic
linking supposedly isn't good and Apple won't support it now? So I
can't run my app without an 

    no such file or directory: 'dynamic_lookup'

5) Bolts Framework was created by Parse and Facebook (As 
   is Parse and ParseUI) I can import Bolts fine in both 
   files in my open source and project directory....
   so it can't be a problem with third party frameworks
```

So I've come to the conclusion that there might be difference between Frameworks and Cocoapods and how can I get a Pods version of the Parse Framework...unless my logic isn't right and they're the same...haha..

Comment: Fixed it. There is a Parse Pods Library, added framework to Pods file and deleted the Parse Framework from project Directory and now I can use it in both

Comment: Remove the answer from the question and put it into the Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. There is a Parse Pods Library, added framework to Pods file and deleted the Parse Framework from project Directory and now I can use it in both

So I'm having trouble accessing frameworks that aren't listed in Cocoapod's website in an open source project that I'm modifying and I'm installing the open source project itself via Cocoapods so the open source project is listed under the Pods Directory.